# Oracle: Explain plan_table query executing order

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to understand the Oracle plan_table and ran few SQL statements to populate the plan_table...From the statements generated in the plan_table, How can I identify the order in which the statements are executed.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Selecting directly from the `PLAN_TABLE` is somewhat "deprecated". At least it's absolutely unnecessary nowadays. You can use `dbms_xplan` to view the execution plan of an explained statement:

```
explain plan for
select *
from your_table;;

select * 
from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```

More details in the manual:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_xplan.htm#CACICEDJ

The manual also contains an example (hierarchical) `SELECT` statement to retrieve the contents from the `PLAN_TABLE` directly:

```
SELECT id, LPAD(' ',2*(LEVEL-1))||operation operation, options,
   object_name, object_alias, qblock_name, position 
FROM plan_table 
START WITH id = 0 AND statement_id = 'xxxxx'
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id AND statement_id = 'xxxxx'
ORDER BY id;
```

The above is taken from: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9010.htm#sthref5965

You need to replace `'xxxx'` with the statement_id you are using (which requires a `set statement_id` in the `explain plan` statement)

Comment: Is there anyway to install Oracle in ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, but you can also download VM images for VirtualBox with it pre-installed on Oracle Linux.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: I fail so see how this is related to my answer. If you have a specific question, then create a new question (probably better on http://dba.stackexchange.com/)